# Howto control CSS Transition in existing JS library called "Sidy.js"?

Tags: javascript, css

I am using in one of my projects (ESP8266 irrigation system) a 3rd party JS library called "Sidy.js", which creates a nice navigation panel using different CSS transitions.

In principle everything works fine, but I have a problem to control appearance and disappearance of the navigation panel from JS.

A demo of Sidy Component can be found [here](https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Multi-functional-jQuery-Off-canvas-Navigation-Plugin-Sidy-js/).

So mainly the question is how to control CSS transitions with JS. I read already some stuff about CSS transitions, but this finally was not helpful for me because I am still a blody CSS beginner.

Here is the CSS Code:

```
/* line 4, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
*,
*:after,
*::before {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

/* line 11, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
html,
body {
  height: 100%; }

/* line 16, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
.sidy__container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%; }

/* line 22, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
.sidy__pusher {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  height: 100%; }
  /* line 28, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
  .sidy__pusher::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s, height 0.1s;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s; }

/* line 39, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
.sidy__content {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%; }

/* line 45, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
.sidy__panel {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: auto;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 100;
    /*background: #333332;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset -10px 0 6px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
      -moz-box-shadow: inset -10px 0 6px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
      box-shadow: inset -10px 0 6px -9px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);*/ }
  /* line 57, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
  .sidy__panel::after {
    position: absolute;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: '';
    opacity: 1;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
    transition: opacity 0.5s; }

/* line 70, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
.sidy--opened .sidy__pusher::after {
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s; }
/* line 77, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
.sidy--opened .sidy__panel::after {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s, height 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s, 0.5s, 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s, width 0.1s 0.5s, height 0.1s 0.5s; }

/* line 86, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
.sidy--after-none::after {
  display: none; }

/* line 90, ../src/scss/sidy.scss */
.sidy--to-open:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  /* overrides chrome default focus outline */ }
```

..and here the JavaScript part:

```
/**!
 * Sidy.js is jQuery plugin for responsive off-, on- canvas
 * sidebar navigation using CSS3 transforms & transitions.
 *
 * Copyright 2014, Reactive Studio, by Dmitriy Bushin
 * dima.bushin@gmail.com
 * MIT licensed.
 *
 * Sidy.js v1.1.0
 * https://github.com/reactivestudio/Sidy.js
 * https://twitter.com/reactive_studio
 *
 * Thanks to Codrops http://tympanus.net/codrops
 * for the inspiration and ideas.
 */

;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
    "use strict";

    var pluginName = "Sidy",
        pluginCssClass = 'sidy',
        buttonAttr = 'data-panel',

        defaults = {
            keyboard: false,

            arrows: true,
            swipe: true,
            trackpad: false,

            panel : {
                position : 'left',
                size     : '300px',
                fx       : 'push',
                duration : 0.65, // time of transition in seconds.
                easing   : 'cubic-bezier(.16, .68, .43, .99)'
            },
        },

        classes = {
            container:     pluginCssClass + '__container',
            content:       pluginCssClass + '__content',
            panel:         pluginCssClass + '__panel',
            pusher:        pluginCssClass + '__pusher',
            opened:        pluginCssClass + '--opened',
            disabled:      pluginCssClass + '--disabled',
            afterNone:     pluginCssClass + '--after-none',
            toOpen:        pluginCssClass + '--to-open',
            toClose:       pluginCssClass + '--to-close',
        },

        mobileCheck = function() {
            var check = false;
            (function(a){if(/(android|ipad|playbook|silk|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))check = true})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
                return check;
        },
        hasParentClass = function(element, classname) {
            var parent = $(element).parents('.'+classname);
            if (parent.length) {
                return true;
            };
            return false;
        },

        eventtype = mobileCheck() ? 'touchstart' : 'click'; // event type (if mobile use touch events)

    // Fx constructor.
    function Fx () {
        var elements = {
                container: {},
                pusher:    {},
                panel:     {}
            };

        this._toggleSize = function(size) {
            return (size.charAt(0) === '-')? size.substr(1) : '-'+size;
        };

        this._cssTranslate3d = function(x, y, z) {
            return {
                webkitTransform: 'translate3d('+x+', '+y+', '+z+')',
                transform:       'translate3d('+x+', '+y+', '+z+')',
            };
        };

        this._cssTransitionAll = function(duration, easing) {
            return {
                webkitTransition: 'all '+duration+'s '+easing,
                transition: 'all '+duration+'s '+easing
            };
        };

        this._cssTransitionTransform = function(duration, easing) {
            return {
                webkitTransition: '-webkit-transform '+duration+'s '+easing,
                transition: 'transform '+duration+'s '+easing
            };
        };

        this._getPosition = function(position, size, offset) {
            var parameters = {
                    opened: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                    },
                    closed: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                    },
                    panelCssRules: {},
                };

            switch (position) {
                case 'left':
                    parameters.opened.x = size;
                    parameters.closed.x = this._toggleSize(offset);
                    parameters.panelCssRules = {
                        top: 0,
                        left: 0,
                        height: '100%',
                        width: size
                    };
                    break;

                case 'right':
                    parameters.opened.x = this._toggleSize(size);
                    parameters.closed.x = offset;
                    parameters.panelCssRules = {
                        top: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        height: '100%',
                        width: size
                    };
                    break;

                case 'top':
                    parameters.opened.y = size;
                    parameters.closed.y = this._toggleSize(offset);
                    parameters.panelCssRules = {
                        top: 0,
                        height: size,
                        width: '100%'
                    };
                    break;

                case 'bottom':
                    parameters.opened.y = this._toogleSize(size);
                    parameters.closed.y = offset;
                    parameters.panelCssRules = {
                        bottom:0,
                        height: size,
                        width: '100%'
                    };
                    break;
            };

            return parameters;
        };

        // Fx template output
        this.output = {
            css: {
                opened: $.extend( {}, elements ),
                closed: $.extend( {}, elements ),
            },
            inPusher:  false,
            afterNone: false,
        };
    };
    Fx.prototype = {
        /* Effect 1: Slide overlay */
        slide_overlay: function (position, size, duration, easing) {
            var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.output),
                p = this._getPosition(position, size, '100%');

            options.css.opened.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {visibility: 'visible'},
                this._cssTranslate3d(0, 0, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                // {visibility: 'visible'},
                this._cssTransitionAll(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.closed.x, p.closed.y, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing)
            );

            options.inPusher  = false;
            options.afterNone = true;

            return options;
        },

        /* Effect 2: Reveal */
        reveal: function (position, size, duration, easing) {
            var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.output),
                p = this._getPosition(position, size, '100%');

            options.css.opened.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                {visibility: 'visible'},
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.opened.x, p.opened.y, 0)
            );

            options.css.opened.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {visibility: 'visible', zIndex: 1},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {zIndex: 1},
                this._cssTransitionAll(duration, easing),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing)
            );

            options.inPusher  = false;
            options.afterNone = true;

            return options;
        },

        /* Effect 3: Push */
        push: function (position, size, duration, easing) {
            var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.output),
                p = this._getPosition(position, size, '100%');

            options.css.opened.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.opened.x, p.opened.y, 0)
            );

            options.css.opened.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {visibility: 'visible'},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.closed.x, p.closed.y, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTransitionAll(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.closed.x, p.closed.y, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing)
            );

            options.inPusher  = true;
            options.afterNone = true;

            return options;
        },

        /* Effect 4: Slide Along */
        slide_along: function (position, size, duration, easing) {
            var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.output),
                p = this._getPosition(position, size, '50%');

            options.css.opened.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.opened.x, p.opened.y, 0)
            );

            options.css.opened.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {visibility: 'visible', zIndex: 1},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(0, 0, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {zIndex: 1},
                this._cssTransitionAll(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.closed.x, p.closed.y, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing)
            );

            options.inPusher  = false;
            options.afterNone = true;

            return options;
        },

        /* Effect 5: Slide Reverse */
        slide_reverse: function (position, size, duration, easing) {
            var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.output),
                p = this._getPosition(position, size, '-50%');

            options.css.opened.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.opened.x, p.opened.y, 0)
            );

            options.css.opened.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {visibility: 'visible', zIndex: 1},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(0, 0, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {zIndex: 1},
                this._cssTransitionAll(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.closed.x, p.closed.y, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing)
            );

            options.inPusher  = false;
            options.afterNone = true;

            return options;
        },

        /* Effect 6: Scale Down */
        scale_down: function (position, size, duration, easing) {
            var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.output),
                p = this._getPosition(position, size, '100%');

            options.css.opened.container = $.extend(
                {},
                {webkitPerspective: '1500px', perspective: '1500px'}
            );

            options.css.opened.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                {
                    webkitTransformStyle: 'preserve-3d',
                    transformStyle:       'preserve-3d'
                },
                this._cssTranslate3d(0, 0, '-300px')
            );

            options.css.opened.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {visibility: 'visible'},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(0, 0, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {opacity: 1},
                this._cssTransitionAll(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.closed.x, p.closed.y, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing)
            );

            options.inPusher  = false;
            options.afterNone = true;

            return options;
        },

        /* Effect 7: Scale Up */
        scale_up: function (position, size, duration, easing) {
            var options = $.extend(true, {}, this.output),
                p = this._getPosition(position, size, '100%');

            options.css.opened.container = $.extend(
                {},
                {
                    webkitPerspective: '1500px',
                    perspective: '1500px',
                    webkitPerspectiveOrigin: '0% 50%',
                    perspectiveOrigin: '0% 50%'
                }
            );

            options.css.opened.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTranslate3d(p.opened.x, p.opened.y, 0)
            );

            options.css.opened.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {visibility: 'visible', opacity: 1, zIndex: 1},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(0, 0, 0),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.panel = $.extend(
                {},
                {opacity: 1, zIndex: 1},
                this._cssTransitionAll(duration, easing),
                this._cssTranslate3d(0, 0, '-300px'),
                p.panelCssRules
            );

            options.css.closed.pusher = $.extend(
                {},
                this._cssTransitionTransform(duration, easing)
            );

            options.inPusher  = false;
            options.afterNone = false;

            return options;
        },
    };

    // Panels constructor.
    function Panels (panelClass, Fx) {
        var self = this;

        $('.' + panelClass).each(function() {
            var $p = $(this),
                optionsFromHTML = {
                    position: $p.attr('data-position'),
                    size:     $p.attr('data-size'),
                    fx:       $p.attr('data-fx'),
                    duration: $p.attr('data-duration'),
                    html:     $p.clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html()
                },
                o = $.extend(
                    {},
                    defaults.panel,
                    optionsFromHTML
                );

            if (o.size === 'auto') {
                o.size = (o.position === 'left' || o.position === 'right')? $p.width()+'px': $p.height()+'px';
            };

            if (!(o.fx in Fx)) {
                console.log(pluginName + ' error: fx with name ' + o.fx + ' does not exists. Sorry');
                o.fx = defaults.panel.fx;
            };

            self[$(this).attr('id')] = $.extend(
                {},
                o,
                Fx[o.fx](o.position, o.size, o.duration, o.easing)
            );
        });
    };

    // Sidy constructor
    function Sidy ( element, optionsHTML ) {
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, optionsHTML );

        this.fx = new Fx(); // Get fx methods
        this.panels = new Panels(classes.panel, this.fx); // Get panels

        var sidy = this;
        sidy.init();
    };
    Sidy.prototype = {
        init: function () {
            var sidy = this,
                contentHTML = $('.' + classes.content).clone().wrap('<div>').parent().html();

            // Build Sidy html template
            $('.' + pluginCssClass)
                .html('')
                .removeClass(pluginCssClass)
                .addClass(classes.container)
                .append('<div></div>');

            $('.' + classes.container + ' div').addClass(classes.pusher);
            $('.' + classes.pusher).html(contentHTML);


            // Panels and add some classes.
            $.each(sidy.panels, function(id, options) {
                var $pusher  = $('.' + classes.pusher),
                    $content = $('.' + classes.content),
                    $div = (options.inPusher) ? $content : $pusher;

                $div.before(options.html);
                $('#'+id)
                    .css(options.css.closed.panel)
                    .addClass(classes.disabled);
            });

            // Get all buttons objects
            sidy.$buttonsOpen  = $('.' + classes.toOpen);
            sidy.$buttonsClose = $('.' + classes.toClose);

            // Add event listeners.
            sidy.$buttonsOpen.on(eventtype, function(event){
                var id = $(this).attr(buttonAttr);
                if (!(id in sidy.panels)) {
                    console.log(pluginName + ' error: panel with id: ' + id + ' does not exists. Sorry');
                } else {
                    sidy.openPanel(event, id, sidy.panels[id]);
                };
            });
        },

        openPanel: function(event, idPanel, options) {
            var sidy = this,
                $container = $('.'+classes.container),
                $panel     = $("#"+idPanel),
                $pusher    = $('.'+classes.pusher);

            // Some magic with disabling multiple events.
            event.stopPropagation();
            event.preventDefault();

            // Enable panel, apply classes for opening panel with fx.
            $panel.removeClass(classes.disabled);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $container
                    .css(options.css.opened.container)
                    .addClass(classes.opened);
                $panel.css(options.css.opened.panel);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $pusher
                        .css(options.css.closed.pusher)
                        .css(options.css.opened.pusher);
                }, 25);
            }, 1);


            // Adding event listeners for closing panel.
            // Close panel if there is a click in nonactive panel area.
            $(document).on(eventtype, function(evt){
                if (! hasParentClass(evt.target, classes.panel)) {
                    sidy.closePanel(idPanel, options);
                    $(this).off();
                };
            });

            // Close panel if there is a close- button or link.
            sidy.$buttonsClose.on(eventtype, function(event) {
                sidy.closePanel(idPanel, options);
                $(this).off();
            });
        },

        closePanel: function(idPanel, options) {
            var $container = $('.'+classes.container),
                $panel     = $("#"+idPanel),
                $pusher    = $('.'+classes.pusher);

            $container.removeClass(classes.opened);
            $panel.attr('style', '').css(options.css.closed.panel);
            $pusher.attr('style', '').css(options.css.closed.pusher);

            setTimeout(function() {
                    $container.attr('style', '');
                    $pusher.attr('style', '');
                    $panel.addClass(classes.disabled);
                }, options.duration*1000 // duration of transition in milliseconds
            );
        }
    };

    $.fn[ pluginName ] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function() {
            if ( !$.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName ) ) {
                $.data( this, "plugin_" + pluginName, new Sidy( this, options ) );
            }
        });
    };


    // Auto-initialization
    $(function () {
        $(this).Sidy();

        // Get usage statistics
        // if (getProtocol() !== 'http://' || !location.host.match(/\./) || window.blockFotoramaData) return;
        // $('body').append('<iframe src="http://data.fotorama.io/?version=' + fotoramaVersion + '" style="display: none;"></iframe>');
    });
})( typeof jQuery !== 'undefined' && jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code here.

Comment: Thank you Brian! Following your advice I added relevant CSS and JS code to my origin question.